# Como remover caracteres não numéricos?

Tags: c, string

Eu quero remover todos os caracteres não numéricos de uma string.
Encontrei a função `isdigit` que poderia me ajudar. Com ela, rodei por todos os caracteres de uma string e aqueles que são numéricos, eu adiciono em outra string.

O problema dessa "solução" é que no fim do algoritmo, a variável de destino possuía não só os caracteres apenas numéricos, mas também todos os outros caracteres da string inicial.

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void apenasNumeros(char *texto, char *dest)
{
    int i, j;
    int length = strlen(texto);

    j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( isdigit(texto[i]) ) {
            dest[j++] = texto[i];
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    char cpf[14] = "123.456.789-00";
    char cpfApenasNumeros[11];

    apenasNumeros(cpf, cpfApenasNumeros);

    printf("%s\n", cpfApenasNumeros);
    getchar();
}
```

A variável cpfApenasNumeros deveria receber o valor 12345678900, mas ele recebe 12345678900123.456.789-00.

Alguém sabe me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado e por quê isso acontece?

Comment: Está funcionando para mim, veja [este link](https://onlinegdb.com/BkEbGrelG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma string tem de terminar sempre em `\0` para estar correta, que lhe faltou colocar na função `apenasNumeros`:

```
void apenasNumeros(char *texto, char *dest)
{
    int i, j;
    int length = strlen(texto);

    j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( isdigit(texto[i]) ) {
            dest[j++] = texto[i];
        }
    }

    dest[j] = '\0'; //terminador aqui
}
```

Os tamanhos que definiu para as strings também não estão corretos pois não contemplam os terminadores e deveriam ser:

```
char cpf[15] = "123.456.789-00";
char cpfApenasNumeros[15];
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/7QUCOm)

Note que no `cpfApenasNumeros` coloquei o mesmo tamanho que o original pois pode potencialmente ter apenas números na string que quer analisar.

Comment: Ahh sim, faz sentido. Tinha me esquecido desse detalhe.
Funcionou perfeitamente